# Laravel Forge Deployment fail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-forge

I'm using Forge for the first time (connected to Digital Ocean), and everything was going well until a recent commit.

I get the following error in Forge:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
13809b0..c8731b5  master     -> origin/master
Updating 13809b0..c8731b5
Fast-forward
resources/views/photos/create.blade.php | 35 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--
1 file changed, 33 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: [32mbeyondcode/laravel-dump-server[39m
Discovered Package: [32mfideloper/proxy[39m
Discovered Package: [32mintervention/image[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlaravel/tinker[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlaravelcollective/html[39m
Discovered Package: [32mnesbot/carbon[39m
Discovered Package: [32mnunomaduro/collision[39m
[32mPackage manifest generated successfully.[39m
php7.3-fpm.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

I haven't deployed a Laravel app before, so am a bit out of my depth.

Should I be restarting `php7.3-fpm.service` on the server?

Apologies for the weak question, but I'm unsure what the rest of the pertinent information would be to provide?

Let me know and I'll add it to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was overall, but I simply restarted the server through Digital Ocean, and all was well.